Subquery to match most recent child table record
Scenario


Requirement.
select all rules that are inactive (Rule_table.Status) matching the most recent audit record with audit_text='status_change' where its created date has passed 6 months.
In the above example, there are 2 audit records that are inactive and  the query SHOULD NOT select Rule_id 4 as its last audit record with audit_text 'Status_Change' is just one month old.
Below is the SQL that i tried (Microsoft SQL server- TSQL)
  select R.Id, A.created_date from Rule R
    join Rule_Audit A on R.id=A.id
    where R.ID= (
      select top1 1 ID from Rule_Audit where Rule_Id=R.Rule_Id and created_date < dateadd 
       (MONTH, -7, GETDATE()) order by created_date desc
    )
  and R.status='Inactive'

But this query gives the result Rule id 4 as the above query matches its audit record 100. Can someone help me with correct query

Please provide test data as text, not as an image.


select all rules that are inactive (Rule_table.Status) matching the most recent audit record with audit_text='status_change' where its created date has passed 6 months.

Breaking down you question, it has 3 parts:

Select all rules that are inactive
But only those, for which, its most recent audit record has an audit_text = 'status_change' and its been 6 month to that status_change event.

Here is the correct query:
WITH MostRecentAudit AS (
  SELECT 
    Rule_Id, 
    MAX(created_date) AS LastAuditDate
  FROM Rule_Audit
  WHERE Audit_Text = 'Status_Change'
  GROUP BY Rule_Id
)
SELECT R.Rule_Id, R.Status, A.LastAuditDate 
FROM Rule R
JOIN MostRecentAudit A ON R.Rule_Id = A.Rule_Id
WHERE R.Status = 'Inactive' 
AND A.LastAuditDate < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE());


It behoovs you to add some test data in text format, but something like this might do the trick:
SELECT  R.Id, x.created_date
FROM    [RULE] R
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  TOP 1 A.*
        FROM    Rule_Audit A
        WHERE   A.id = R.id
        AND A.audit_text='status_change'
        ORDER BY A.created_date DESC
    ) x
WHERE   x.created_date < dateadd(MONTH, -7, GETDATE())
AND R.status='Inactive'

This way, you first get the latest rule audit, and then outside of the APPLY fetch so it's at least 7 months old
